Maps in pdf format generated by python cartopy cannot be concatenated in illustrator (possibly due to Outlines outside the artboard scope)
I want to use illustrator to concatenate my PDF graphics, which were generated using python cartopy. But when I moved the two maps closer, I got an error and I couldn't move the maps. The detailed error information is as follows: Error: Can't move the objects. The requested transformation would make some objects fall completely off the drawing area.

Then I turn on outline mode (Ctrl+Y), you can see that there are a lot of outlines outside the artboard, which may be the reason why the graphics can not be joined.
I tried to select and delete these lines outside the artboard, but I did not succeed, I hope to get professional help here. Thank you all in advance for your help.

This probably needs more details about how exactly you are exporting them. Why don't you export the entire thing and postprocess it in Illustrator? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Try to take a single map, then release any clipping masks that are present. That or select all and scale it down 50% before moving anything. This question is more about how to use Illustrator than anything else and would be better suited to http://superuser.com
